# Specify a dependency from a local gitlab server in an environment.yml file

Tags: python, conda

According to the documentation, I can create a python environment by incorporating dependencies specified in a file named `environment.yml`

[**`conda env create -f environment.yml`**](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-from-an-environment-yml-file)

I can generate the `yml` by

[**`conda env export > environment.yml`**](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#exporting-the-environment-file)

In the file I see a spot for `pip` installs:

```
- pip:
  - backports.shutil-get-terminal-size==1.0.0
  - conda==4.3.30
  - conda-build==3.0.22
  - conda-verify==2.0.0
  - et-xmlfile==1.0.1
  - ipython-genutils==0.2.0
  - jupyter-client==5.1.0
  - jupyter-console==5.2.0
  - jupyter-core==4.3.0
  - jupyterlab-launcher==0.4.0
  - nb-conda-kernels==2.1.0
  - prompt-toolkit==1.0.15
  - ruamel-yaml==0.11.14
  - tables==3.4.2
```

However, I need to include a dependency on a library from a local gitlab server.  How must I specify that in this `yml` file?